# Linq Data Can Not Be Null By Using Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedures, entity

I tried to use a stored procedure with linq.

If `result.FirstOrDefault().CustomerName` is null, I get the following exception,

> NullReferenceException was unhandled
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

With the following code:

```
var result = context.sp_CustomerInformation(CustomerId).ToList();
var MyCustomerName = result.FirstOrDefault().CustomerName;
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into that error because `FirstOrDefault()` will return the default value of the type when the result has not matches. In this case, the default value is null. So you're attempting to access a property of a null object which will result in a `NullReferenceException`.

You need to something like:

```
var result = context.sp_CustomerInformation(CustomerId).ToList();
var object = result.FirstOrDefault();
var MyCustomerName = "";

if(object != null)
    MyCustomerName = object.CustomerName;
else
    // do something here if there were no results
```

For what it's worth you can probably combine your `result` query as well:

```
var result = context.sp_CustomerInformation(CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();
```

instead of `ToList()` which will return all matching records. `FirstOrDefault` will only get the first record. Then you would be able to use `result` instead of `object` from the above example.